# Connectedness of the complement of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Show that the complement of the graph is **connected**

if the diameter of the graph is 3

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if the distance from vertex $s$ to vertex $t$ is $3$, then $(s,t)$ is not an edge, and for every vertex $v$, $(s,v)$ or $(v,t)$ is not an edge.